# Enabling loop and interrupt

Tags: python, pi-4

I am a complete novice and would like some help with simple code.
I am using a Pi4 and learning Python to code. I need to create a loop that counts pulse inputs to a certain number then triggers an output PWM - ie: 20 to 1. Want to use on a fuel meter to install an additive.
I would use another input pin to turn the output on/off as the pulse is always present but don't want constant output unless asking for the additive. The control pin would need to go low to activate the output. I can handle the conversion voltage into the Pi4 and work with the output voltage, it's the actual code I am having the issue with.
I can find lots of info on using timing factors but not actual variable pulses. Input pulses are to a maximum of 100H.

Any help or direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Ah, let me see. You can use Rpi python to do the job. You can use one GPIO input pin to detect the pulses, similar to that of reading a manual push button. Let Rpi python counts the pulses, and when count is up, use another GPIO output pin to turn on/off a switch, just like turning on/off a LED.  I usually suggest newbies to start off with learn "blinking a LED" form the official Rpi newbie tutorials. You might also like to later learn how to use a "relay" to turn on/off your heater etc.